# Android Horizontal Images slider

Tags: android, listview, zooming, horizontal-scrolling, horizontallist

Hi I need to achieve a horizontal image scroller in which the images towards the centre will be  zoomed more.

[image: Required Image scrolller style]

I could achieve somewhat close with horizontal listview and Circular drawable.
 Now I nedd means to give a focus to items in centre by applying a zoom How can this be achieved ?

This is what I have done so far 
[image: Achieved so far]

Thank You

Comment: what are you using for horizontal listview ? i meant listview or some library

Comment: Hi @PreethiRao, I am using a library. I am actually developing in Xamarin. So I am using a Xamarin library

Comment: does it give callback on scroll listerner and gives the count of visible items.. Like normal listview

Comment: yes it is just like a listview. We can get the position of the current item from a GetView callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry that time by mistake half answer got posted, i am not sure with values but logic is proper , just calculate the mid element in onscroll listener and get the view and apply the animation.
This should be implemented in your onScrollListener of your listview.

```
 @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                    int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                        int start = firstVisibleItem ;
                        int end = start + visibleItemCount ;
                       // calculate the mid element
                        int midElement = start + visibleItemCount/2;
                        View imageView = getchildAt(midElement - start);
                       //apply animation
                    }
        }
```